# WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW equivalent in xlib

Tags: c++, window, xlib

I'm porting some simple c++ code from win7 to linux (Xlib).
Some point i have to create a "toolbar" window that mustn't appear on the desktop.
On windows i do it by passing `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` to `CreateWindowEx`.
But how can i do it with xlib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: _NET_WM_STATE_SKIP_TASKBAR,
Source:
http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.3.html#id2507144